# host ubuntu and guest Windows access each other from command line?

Tags: virtualbox, ssh

My host OS is Ubuntu 14.04, and guest is Windows 8.1 running in a virtual machine by VirtualBox.

Is it possible to

- access the guest Windows from host Ubuntu from Ubuntu's bash?
- access the host Ubuntu from  the guest Windows from Windows' shell such as powershell?

Will these be done by ssh? What software I need to run on host and on guest? What are there addresses to connect to?

Thanks.

Comment: Define "access".

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can install a ssh server on the windows guest. Options range from cygwin and several ssh servers are available.

See http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-server-2008/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html

You can download cygwin here - https://www.cygwin.com/

When you run the installer (cygwin.exe) you may choose what to install. search for openssh , last I looked client and server were packaged together as "openssh"

[image]

Full tutorial - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Once the ssh server is installed , configured, and running in the windows guest you simply

```
ssh user@windows_ip_address
```

I am assuming you know how to use a ssh client, if not see http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_overview